# How to import database from heroku to Dokku on DegitalOcean?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, digital-ocean, dokku

On local - capture backup:

```
heroku pg:backups capture
heroku pg:backups public-url
```

copy public-url

On DigitalOcean console - Download dump to droplet:

```
curl -o latest.dump [public-url]
dokku postgres:import db < latest.dump
```

imports start. I have much errors like such:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2638; 1259 266102 INDEX index_XXX rnhgerttwiaqyf
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  index "index_XXX" does not exist
    Command was: DROP INDEX public.index_XXX;
```

and etc

After import i have some fine tables in database.
But some tables are blank.

How make import dump from Heroku to Dokku postgres db on DO?

Comment: I recapture and download backup to server again - all fine. Seems buckup file was be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to this plugin `https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres`

What you did was actually correct, it wasn't due to corrupted file but due to the fact that the Indexes were not there to begin with.
On the second import, it ran without errors when the Indexes exist.